# Windows Server 2012 R2 - File Server/FTP over SSL

Tags: security, ssl, ftps

I am a student and for my dissertation I need to configure a Windows Server to be a file server which uses FTP over SSL for file sharing so a user can download a file from the server.
What do I need to do that in terms of setting up the service and calling it from another machine later on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this your homework assignment?

Comment: No, its not..I am actually experimenting on idle scanning techniques and the use of IPID headers from a penetration tester perspective. This is just my test machine and since I got little experience on setting up Windows servers(mostly working with Linux) I needed some help.

Comment: I see, i'm sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.**  Install an SSL certificate on the server.

- You can buy the SSL certificate from your webhost
- Your webhost should also have instructions for installing the certificate
- If you can't find instructions, try this:  [GoDaddy SSL Instructions](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623)

**Step 2.**  Set up an FTP server on your Windows server

- You can set up an FTP server using IIS (Internet Information Services) which is installed by default on every Windows Server.
- Once you open IIS, right click on the Server name and select add FTP Site.
- Give it a name and a location where you want to save the files that you'll be uploading
- You can leave the IP on **All Unassigned** and port on 21
- Select **Require SSL** and use the Select button to navigate to your certificate
- Enable basic authentication, leave anonymous disabled

**Step 3.**  Grant user permissions

- Open **Computer Management** and navigate to "Users" under System Tools / Local Users and Groups.
- If there is no user called **ftpuser**, create one.
- In File Explorer, right click on the folder where you'll be storing your files, select Properties and go to the Security tab.
- Click the Edit button, then Add
- Enter in the name of your ftp user, click Check Names, then OK.
- Your ftp user should now be listed in the security tab.  Select this user and then grant Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, Read, Write.  Click OK.
- In IIS, select your ftp site and then double click "FTP Authorization Rules".  Add a new rule for a specific user (ftpuser) and select Read and Write.

**Step 4.**  Connect to your FTP server from your local machine

- There are many ways to connect to your ftp server including a browser or file explorer, but arguably the best way to do this is to use an FTP client.
- A good free FTP client is Cute FTP.  I recommend it, but there are many others.
- After you've installed an ftp client, enter in your host name (domain or server ip), user (ftp user you created), password and port number (should be 21).
- Now you can drag and drop from and to your server.
- Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Vincent! Just a silly question. I specifically need to download files via FTP over SSL from another virtual machine on my lab. Do these steps suffice or do I need to add some more to make this possible?

Comment: I've never done it over a VM but I can't see why it would be any different.